# Perl CVS getting data to enter in command

Tags: perl

Trying to get CVS data Name and IP for now and put it within a command to do bulk creation. I'm stuck here here are the compile errors:

```
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at ./interoperable.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$ip" requires explicit package name at ./interoperable.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name at ./interoperable.pl line 11.
Global symbol "$ip" requires explicit package name at ./interoperable.pl line 11.
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {
     $name;
     $ip;

     my $command = "mgmt_cli add generic-object create 
     \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiGatewayPlain\" name \"$name\" ipaddr \"$ip\" 
     thirdPartyEncryption \"True\" osInfo.osName \"Gaia\"
    vpn.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpn\" vpn.owned- 
       object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.create 
       \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpnClientsSettingsForGateway\" VPN.
     owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.create 
      \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiEndpointVpnClientSettingsForGateway\" vpn.owned- 
     object.vpnCli
      entsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.owned-object.endpointVpnEnable 
    \"True\" vpn.owned-object.ike.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiIke\" 
    vpn.owned-obj
     ect.sslNe.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiSslNetworkExtender\" vpn.owned- 
    object.sslNe.owned-object.sslEnable \"False\" vpn.owned-object.sslNe.owned- 
    object.gwCertificate \"def
     aultCert\" vpn.owned-object.isakmpUniversalSupport \"True\"";
      #@out=();
      #print $command

      # Note: this could be a full file path
      my $filename = "ssg_test1.csv";

      open(INPUT, $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";
      # Read the header line.
      my $line = <INPUT>;

      while ($line = <INPUT>) {
          chomp($line);
          my ($name, $ip) = split(',', $line);

          # Display the header, just to check things are working.
          print($line);
    }
    close(INPUT);
}

main();
```

Comment: Those warnings mean that you have failed to declare those variables. E.g. `my $ip`

Answer (score 2):

If you get Perl warnings or errors that you don't understand, then you can get more help by adding `use diagnostics` to your code (but remove it again before putting the code into production). In this case, you would get a message like this:

> (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"), declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say which package the global variable is in (using "::").

So you need to declare your variables with `my`.

Your best solution is to replace the two lines

```
$name;
$ip;
```

with the following declaration:

```
my ($name, $ip);
```

Comment: Thank you! seems I can print the output of the CVS but I need it to actually add the variables on the command so an example  mgmt_cli add generic-object create "com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiGatewayPlain" name "test1" ipaddr "10.1.1.1" thirdPartyEncryption "True" osInfo.osName "Gaia" ----adding the name and  IP per line I have on the CSV

Comment: @user1026398 You can't change the question when you get an answer. The question you asked is answered. If you have more things to ask about, start a new question.